# Motivation of Keeping Supersymmetry in String Compactification

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, compactification

In Candelas, Horowitz, Strominger, and Witten's famous paper [1] about string compactification, they ask that supersymmetry should not be broken in the resulting 4d theory. Then combined with other reasonable requirements, they concluded that the 6d compactified space has to be a Calabi-Yau manifold. By "supersymmetry should not be broken", we mean it is unbroken at the Planck (or compactification) scale.

I can understand that keeping supersymmetry can solve the [hierarchy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchy_problem). But I want more arguments/motivation. Could anyone help me? The more the better.

[[1]](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(85)90602-9) Candelas, P., et al. “Vacuum configurations for superstrings.” Nuc. Phys. B258, 46–74
(1985).

Comment: How about explaining dark matter and unification of gauge couplings?

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain in more detail? It seems to me that string theory has a huge enough symmetry group to help unify gauge couplings. What's the role 4d-SUSY playing in this story? As for the dark matter, I barely know anything.

Comment: It's not so much the embedding of the SU(3)xSU(2)xU(1) in a larger group as getting all three running couplings to intersect at around the Planck scale, see e.g. the N=1 MSSM; R-parity conservation leads to e.g. stable neutralinos which are dark matter candidates

Comment: It is informative. Thank you very much!

Comment: In addition to what @NiharKarve wrote, there is also the issue of stability of the resulting vacuum solution - after the compactification I mean

Comment: Cool! Stability of vacuum! I also heard some arguments about beta function, for the theory to keep a CFT under RG flow. But I failed to find detailed computations.

Answer (score 1):

The motivation is that supersymmetry is actually a consistency condition for string theory. Non-supersymmetric string theories [exist](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0370269386915248?via%3Dihub) but all of them have problems such as tachyons or anomalies.

Other interesting point is that we don't know any single example of a stable non-supersymmetric vacua constructed within string theory. This does not imply in any way that superstring theory should be unable to describe non-supersymmetric physics, it's just that maybe string theory is predicting that the only universes that will last forever are the supersymmetric ones; the rest of them belong to the swampland or are meta-satble, as it seems to be the case of our universe. You can hear this point of view in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q7SCciWasDc) talk of Cumrun Vafa (min3 7:42).

**Reference:**

[Why string theory implies supersymmetry](https://motls.blogspot.com/2010/06/why-string-theory-implies-supersymmetry.html).

Comment: This seems an argument of why string theory must show up with SUSY, not why we should keep SUSY in the resulting 4d theory in contrast with break it during compactification.

Comment: @Youran It doesn't matter if you have string theory on a product manifold, flat space or with all dimensions curled up. The theory is still string theory and still obey all the restrictions that a string theory should obey, the existence of supersymmetry in this case.